# Creating accessLevel group bindings with GCP: Why do all of my approaches (Terraform, gcloud CLI, and REST API) fail with INVALID_ARGUMENT?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, terraform, gcloud, terraform-provider-gcp

I am trying to bind an accessLevel to a group that I have created in google groups. I have tried creating the biding in terraform, through the gcloud cli, and using the rest API. All 3 fail with an INVALID_ARGUMENT exception.

I tried the following approaches

Terraform:

```
resource "google_access_context_manager_access_policy" "access-policy" {
  parent = "organizations/123456789"
  title  = "${var.ENV} Access Policy"
  scopes = ["projects/${lookup(var.project_number, var.ENV)}"]
}

resource "google_access_context_manager_access_level" "firewall-console-access" {
  parent = "accessPolicies/${google_access_context_manager_access_policy.access-policy.name}"
  name   = "accessPolicies/${google_access_context_manager_access_policy.access-policy.name}/accessLevels/firewall_console_access"
  title  = "firewall_console_access"
  basic {
    conditions {
      ip_subnetworks = [
        "182.0.0.0/24"
      ]
      regions = [
        "CA",
      ]
    }
  }
}

resource "google_access_context_manager_gcp_user_access_binding" "console-group-access" {
  organization_id = "123456789"
  group_key       = "test-group-key"
  access_levels   = [
    google_access_context_manager_access_level.firewall-console-access.name
  ]
}
```

Result:

The scoped access policy and the access level were created successfully:
`gcloud access-context-manager levels list --policy 123456789` >> `NAME: firewall_console_access TITLE: firewall_console_access LEVEL_TYPE: Basic`

but the binding fails with the following error:

[image: terraform apply result]

gcloud cli:

```
$ gcloud access-context-manager cloud-bindings create --level="accessPolicies/123456789/accessLevels/firewall_console_access" --group-key="test-group-key" --organization="123456789"
ERROR: (gcloud.access-context-manager.cloud-bindings.create) INVALID_ARGUMENT: Request contains an invalid argument.
```

API:

request.json >>

```
{
  "groupKey": "test-group-key",
  "accessLevels": [ "accessPolicies/123456789/accessLevels/firewall_console_access" ]
}
```

```
curl -X POST     -H "Authorization: Bearer $(gcloud auth print-access-token)"     -H "Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8"     -d @request.json     "https://accesscontextmanager.googleapis.com/v1/organizations/123456789/gcpUserAccessBindings"
{
  "error": {
    "code": 400,
    "message": "Request contains an invalid argument.",
    "status": "INVALID_ARGUMENT"
  }
}
```

EDIT:

I thought that maybe this error was due to the accessPolicy being scoped at the project level so I created another access level that was bound to my organizations default policy and tried to use the new access level in the binding, same issue.

[image: unscoped access level binding]

Comment: Show the `gcloud access-context-manager levels create` command and YAML that you used.

Comment: The access level was successfully created using terraform cl defined in the snippet above. Only creation of the binding fails.

Here's the summary of the access level:
```
gcloud access-context-manager levels list --policy 123456789
NAME: firewall_console_access
TITLE: firewall_console_access
LEVEL_TYPE: Basic
```

Comment: Please put that in your post. The reason I ask is that is the common denominator for each command. Also include `request.json`.

Answer (score 1):

You need to provide google group key id into group key, gcloud command to fetch group key id is **gcloud identity groups describe groupname@alias.com**